# Formatting telephone number to match specific pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was wondering if there is a nice way to format a number against a set string pattern, I want to use different phone numbers like `0123456789` that gets output as `012-345-6789` and `001123456789` that gets output as `00-11-234-567` etc. I was thinking of having the pattern as a data attribute on the input like `data-format="xxx-xxx-xxxx"` or `"xx-xx-xxx-xxx"` depending on what is selected then trying to match the input number to this pattern but completely sure how to achieve this or if it's the correct approach? This format doesn't need to be reflected in the input, the format will be used in presenting the number in a summary.

**Example code:**

```
<form action="" class="js-form">
    <label>Telephone Number</label>
    <input type="number" class="js-phone" data-format="xx-xx-xxx-xxx">
    <input type="submit" class="js-submit">
</form>

function formatTelephone(number, format) {
    // split number
    // loop number
    // pop each character
    // .replace pattern
}

$formAction.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var telephoneNumber = $phoneInput.val(),
        telephoneFormat = $phoneInput.data('format');

    formatTelephone(telephoneNumber, telephoneFormat);
});
```

Should I split the number, loop through each character and .replace the corresponding pattern character whilst avoiding the dashes somehow?

Comment: is it will use for validation or what.?

Comment: No not validation, it will be formatted to present in a contact form summary, so formatted then saved to a model

Comment: which format you want to show.? does no of length will vary.?

Comment: The format will be dictated by the country selected by user, so one country format could be xx-xx-xxx-xxx and another xxx-xxx-xxxx, length will vary accordingly and a character length will be done to make sure the right amount is in place to make the pattern update

Comment: you might see https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber that might help you

Answer (score 0):

- strip all non-numeric characters from the number first
- loop through all characters in the format, if char='x' then put the corresponding digit from the stripped number to that position, if not - leave the character from the format in the resulting string.

You should keep track of the position in the number, incrementing it when you put the digit. And first you should validate the format itself by counting x.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I just created and it works.

It was necessary to change the `input type` to `text` otherwise it wouldn't accept the `-` since it accepts only numbers.

```
<form action="" class="js-form">
    <label>Telephone Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="js-phone" data-format="xxx-xxx-xxxx"/>
    <input type="submit" class="js-submit"/>
</form>
```

I have commented the JS:

```
$('.js-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // I'm passing the object and not the value so I'll be able to update its value
    // at the end of the function execution
    var telephoneNumber = $('.js-phone'),
        telephoneFormat = $('.js-phone').data('format');

    formatTelephone(telephoneNumber, telephoneFormat);
});

function formatTelephone(number, format) {
    // Considering that - will always be the separator
    patternList = format.split('-');
    pattern = ""
    // Creates the regex as a string
    // The \\ in the pattern was required to escape the \, which is required in this case
    patternList.forEach(function(x) {
        pattern += "(\\d{0,"+x.length+"})";
    });
    // Create the RegExp
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    // Try to match it with the number passed in the parameter
    var result = number.val().match(regex);
    // Will store the formatted number
    formatted = "";
    // Loop through the patterList to add the - back
    for(x=1;x<=patternList.length; x++) {
        formatted += (result[x] + (x==patternList.length ? '' : '-'));
    }
    // Now you can do whatever you need with the formatted variable
    number.val(formatted);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58t9tj6b/)